# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (1,1,3)

Tags: python, numpy

Unable to solve this error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (1,1,3). how can I successfully use the reshape function to solve this error? Thank you

```
    387 train_data_mean = np.array([[[mean, mean, mean]]])  
    388 train_data_std = np.array([[[std, std, std]]])  
--> 389 train_data = (train_data - train_data_mean) / (train_data_std + 1e-7)
```

Comment: how can you make something from nothing? Can you give an example how (0,) tensor should look like after being broadcast to (1,) ?

Comment: Your `train_data` vector is empty.

Comment: Check the `shape` of the arrays in the problem line.  That `train_data_mean` is (1,1,3) should be obvious from the construction in 387.  But what is `train_data`?